# Silverstripe URL patterns $url_handlers not working - namespaces seem to conflict

Tags: php, routes, silverstripe

When I try to create the routes for a RESTful API with the following `$url_handlers`, it seems to create a conflict between two of the patterns.

```
class API extends Controller {

    ...

    private static $url_handlers = array(
        'GET object' => 'read',
        'POST object' => 'create',
        'PUT object/$ID' => 'update',
        'PUT object/$ID/$OtherID' => 'assign',
        'DELETE object/$ID' => 'delete',
        'DELETE object/$ID/$OtherID' => 'unassign',
    );

    ...
}
```

`object/1` works fine, but `object/1/1` is matching to the `update` action.

What extra detail do I add to make these patterns work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of *zippy* and *flamerohr* on [Silverstripe Users Slack](https://silverstripe-users.slack.com/messages)

---

URL patterns should be defined in the order of *most-specific* to *least-specific*.

## Option 1:

Re-order the patterns correctly, and add a static segment between variables, so that the added specificity avoids the pattern from matching when it shouldn't e.g

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'GET object' => 'read',
    'POST object' => 'create',
    'PUT object/$ID/static-segment/$OtherID' => 'assign',
    'PUT object/$ID' => 'update',
    'DELETE object/$ID/static-segment/$OtherID' => 'unassign',
    'DELETE object/$ID' => 'delete',
);
```

## Option 2:

Re-order the patterns correctly, and use the `!` convention to define that a URL parameter must be provided in order to match the pattern e.g

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'GET object' => 'read',
    'POST object' => 'create',
    'PUT object/$ID/$OtherID!' => 'assign',
    'PUT object/$ID' => 'update',
    'DELETE object/$ID/$OtherID!' => 'unassign',
    'DELETE object/$ID' => 'delete',
);
```

This convention can be found in Silverstripe's `Routing` documentation:
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/controllers/routing/#url-patterns